# Facebook Native Ads video height Android

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-android-sdk, facebook-ads-api

I have been implementing Facebook Native Ads for Android according to this guide:
[Native ads for Android](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/audience-network/android/native-api)

And i have this problem:
When i set width and height of my parent view to WRAP_CONTENT, all static ads(images) are sized and shown fine. But when video ad is shown, it always takes full device's height and video is stretched. 
The only case, when video ad is not stretched to full height -- is when i set a fixed height(in dp). In any other case it stretches itself, ignoring all height parameters. 
If anyone have encountered similar problem -- i really would appreciate some help.

Comment: did you find the solution for WRAP_CONTENT?

Comment: did you found any solution? I am also having same issue.